# htaccess redirect url with domain as variable to an external site

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect

```
http://example.com/report?domain=dollarshaveclub.com
```

to

```
http://www.semrush.com/info/dollarshaveclub.com+%28by+organic%29
```

I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^?domain=$
RewriteRule ^report$ http://www.semrush.com/info/$1+%28by+organic%29 [R=301,L]
```

But I'm not getting anywhere...What could I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution finally:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^domain=(.*)
RewriteRule ^report(.*) http://www.semrush.com/info/%1+(by+organic)? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You must remove the `R=301,` part.

This works for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^report$ http://www.semrush.com/info/$1+%28by+organic%29 [NC]
```

Comment: Try if it works without the query string and without the condition